# Store the uploaded file in the temporary folder created in the project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used a component art file upload feature wherein i want the browsed file when saved have to be saved in the temporary folder created in the project. How can i do that?
My code:

```
<ComponentArt:Upload
        ID="Upload1"
        RunAt="server"
        MaximumFileCount="1"
        AutoPostBack="true"
        onclick="btnFileUpload_Click"
         </ComponentArt:Upload>
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of the ComponentArt component? Because I am totally sure what you ask for here is basically probably the first example for that component.

Comment: yes i have read the documentation and done accordingly but getting an error : Upload1.TempFileFolder = Server.MapPath("E://MVP-IQ//Media Files//");
Am i doing any mistake in the way of mentioning path?

Comment: Yeah. "I get an error" followed be no error description is SOOOO helpfull. What about you come up with an excuse why we should not know the error - or actually just provide the error?

Comment: @TomTom: I did not get you. What exactly you want me to specify? I went through the documentation and got the settings done in the web.config and that error above i am getting in the c# code while specifying the path.

Comment: You said you get an error. How can we even try to help you if you do not tell u what error? There is no error above - only a line of code. "An error" is not smart to say for someone claiming to know even a day programming. If there is an error, provide the relevant information.

Comment: I got the error in the path mentioning.Can you please tell me how do i mention the path of any folder?

Comment: You get "THE" error. WHAT ERROR? I kee3p telling you to tell details about the error, you keep telling me "an error". Maybe get a book about Programming first and learn a little of it? Errors have a message, an exception type.

Comment: I got a error in mentioning the path and the error says :'E:/MVP-IQ/Media Files' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected. What is virtual path?

Comment: Ah, so finally. Took only half a dozen questions. Have you considered reading the documentation for Server.MapPath?

Comment: what does readind means?

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of back and forth - as you finally declare what error you get:

> I got a error in mentioning the path and the error says :'E:/MVP-IQ/Media Files' is a 
>   physical path, but a virtual path was expected. What is virtual path?

the question is totally not realted to the ComponentArt component but basically a failure to read the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx

Let me quote for you:

> Specifies the relative or virtual path to map to a physical directory.
>   If Path starts with either a forward (/) or backward slash (), the
>   MapPath method returns a path as if Path were a full, virtual path. If
>   Path doesn't start with a slash, the MapPath method returns a path
>   relative to the directory of the .asp file being processed.

MapPath is made to map from a site internal path ("/Files") to the file based on the directory structure ("C:\www\files") because a website has no defined knowledgee where it resides on the disc.

As such, calling it with an absolute path as you do:

> Server.MapPath("E://MVP-IQ//Media Files//");

is not legal - if you know where the path is, yuo do not need MapPath. If you need to add a directory to that, then do that (System.IO.Directory class has methods). MapPath is onyl there to get you a disc based path from a site / page relative path.

THere are examples in the link above. It always helps to

- Read the documentation
- Say WHAT error you get.

Comment: I am sorry for the above thing since i was totally frustrated and also i am totally new to this. I will refer to the documentation once again and get back to you. thanx alot.